# Apache Spark cause Tomcat to graceful shutdown

Tags: tomcat, apache-spark, tomcat7

Tomcat version: `7.0.47`

I have a web application which use Apache Spark. My web application act as a Apache spark driver program.

When remote standalone spark cluster is not available then Spark context is shutting down with log `org.apache.spark.util.Utils - Shutdown hook called`

Sooner this happens Tomcat also starting to shut down gracefully. The only log I can see in tomcat is `[exec] Result: 50`

What would be the reason for Tomcat to shutting down when spark calling it's shut down hook ?

Spark Log

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/data/downloads/spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/spark-assembly-1.4.1-hadoop2.6.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/data/downloads/spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/spark-examples-1.4.1-hadoop2.6.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
15/12/09 17:11:23 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 1.4.1
15/12/09 17:11:24 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
15/12/09 17:11:24 WARN Utils: Your hostname, pesamara-mobl-vm1 resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.0.1; using 10.30.9.107 instead (on interface eth0)
15/12/09 17:11:24 WARN Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
15/12/09 17:11:25 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: pes
15/12/09 17:11:25 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: pes
15/12/09 17:11:25 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(pes); users with modify permissions: Set(pes)
15/12/09 17:11:26 INFO Slf4jLogger: Slf4jLogger started
15/12/09 17:11:27 INFO Remoting: Starting remoting
15/12/09 17:11:27 INFO Remoting: Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://sparkDriver@10.30.9.107:55740]
15/12/09 17:11:27 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 55740.
15/12/09 17:11:27 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
15/12/09 17:11:27 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
15/12/09 17:11:27 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /tmp/spark-30d61b03-0b1c-4250-b68e-c2404c7884a8/blockmgr-3226ed7e-f8e5-40a2-bfb1-ffabb51cd0e0
15/12/09 17:11:28 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 491.5 MB
15/12/09 17:11:28 INFO HttpFileServer: HTTP File server directory is /tmp/spark-30d61b03-0b1c-4250-b68e-c2404c7884a8/httpd-7f2572c2-5677-446e-a80a-6f9d05ee2891
15/12/09 17:11:28 INFO HttpServer: Starting HTTP Server
15/12/09 17:11:28 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'HTTP file server' on port 45047.
15/12/09 17:11:28 INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
15/12/09 17:11:28 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
15/12/09 17:11:28 INFO SparkUI: Started SparkUI at http://10.30.9.107:4040
15/12/09 17:11:29 INFO FairSchedulableBuilder: Created default pool default, schedulingMode: FIFO, minShare: 0, weight: 1
15/12/09 17:11:29 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Connecting to master akka.tcp://sparkMaster@localhost2:7077/user/Master...
15/12/09 17:11:29 WARN AppClient$ClientActor: Could not connect to akka.tcp://sparkMaster@localhost2:7077: akka.remote.InvalidAssociation: Invalid address: akka.tcp://sparkMaster@localhost2:7077
15/12/09 17:11:29 WARN Remoting: Tried to associate with unreachable remote address [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@localhost2:7077]. Address is now gated for 5000 ms, all messages to this address will be delivered to dead letters. Reason: localhost2: unknown error
15/12/09 17:11:49 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Connecting to master akka.tcp://sparkMaster@localhost2:7077/user/Master...
15/12/09 17:11:49 WARN AppClient$ClientActor: Could not connect to akka.tcp://sparkMaster@localhost2:7077: akka.remote.InvalidAssociation: Invalid address: akka.tcp://sparkMaster@localhost2:7077
15/12/09 17:11:49 WARN Remoting: Tried to associate with unreachable remote address [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@localhost2:7077]. Address is now gated for 5000 ms, all messages to this address will be delivered to dead letters. Reason: localhost2: unknown error
15/12/09 17:12:09 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Connecting to master akka.tcp://sparkMaster@localhost2:7077/user/Master...
15/12/09 17:12:09 WARN AppClient$ClientActor: Could not connect to akka.tcp://sparkMaster@localhost2:7077: akka.remote.InvalidAssociation: Invalid address: akka.tcp://sparkMaster@localhost2:7077
15/12/09 17:12:09 WARN Remoting: Tried to associate with unreachable remote address [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@localhost2:7077]. Address is now gated for 5000 ms, all messages to this address will be delivered to dead letters. Reason: localhost2: unknown error
15/12/09 17:12:29 ERROR SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Application has been killed. Reason: All masters are unresponsive! Giving up.
15/12/09 17:12:29 WARN SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Application ID is not initialized yet.
15/12/09 17:12:29 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://10.30.9.107:4040
15/12/09 17:12:29 INFO DAGScheduler: Stopping DAGScheduler
15/12/09 17:12:29 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Shutting down all executors
15/12/09 17:12:29 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Asking each executor to shut down
15/12/09 17:12:29 ERROR OneForOneStrategy: 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.client.AppClient$ClientActor$$anonfun$receiveWithLogging$1.applyOrElse(AppClient.scala:160)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction$mcVL$sp.apply$mcVL$sp(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:33)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction$mcVL$sp.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:33)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction$mcVL$sp.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:25)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ActorLogReceive$$anon$1.apply(ActorLogReceive.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ActorLogReceive$$anon$1.apply(ActorLogReceive.scala:42)
    at scala.PartialFunction$class.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:118)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ActorLogReceive$$anon$1.applyOrElse(ActorLogReceive.scala:42)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:465)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.client.AppClient$ClientActor.aroundReceive(AppClient.scala:61)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:516)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:487)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:238)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:220)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:393)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
15/12/09 17:12:29 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Connecting to master akka.tcp://sparkMaster@localhost2:7077/user/Master...
15/12/09 17:12:29 WARN AppClient$ClientActor: Could not connect to akka.tcp://sparkMaster@localhost2:7077: akka.remote.InvalidAssociation: Invalid address: akka.tcp://sparkMaster@localhost2:7077
15/12/09 17:12:29 WARN Remoting: Tried to associate with unreachable remote address [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@localhost2:7077]. Address is now gated for 5000 ms, all messages to this address will be delivered to dead letters. Reason: localhost2: unknown error
15/12/09 17:12:29 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 54184.
15/12/09 17:12:29 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 54184
15/12/09 17:12:29 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Trying to register BlockManager
15/12/09 17:12:29 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager 10.30.9.107:54184 with 491.5 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, 10.30.9.107, 54184)
15/12/09 17:12:29 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager
15/12/09 17:12:30 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call methods on a stopped SparkContext
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.org$apache$spark$SparkContext$$assertNotStopped(SparkContext.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.getSchedulingMode(SparkContext.scala:1503)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.postEnvironmentUpdate(SparkContext.scala:2007)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:543)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.examples.sql.SparkContextTest.main(SparkContextTest.java:32)
15/12/09 17:12:30 INFO SparkContext: SparkContext already stopped.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call methods on a stopped SparkContext
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.org$apache$spark$SparkContext$$assertNotStopped(SparkContext.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.getSchedulingMode(SparkContext.scala:1503)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.postEnvironmentUpdate(SparkContext.scala:2007)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:543)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.examples.sql.SparkContextTest.main(SparkContextTest.java:32)
15/12/09 17:12:30 INFO DiskBlockManager: Shutdown hook called
15/12/09 17:12:30 INFO Utils: path = /tmp/spark-30d61b03-0b1c-4250-b68e-c2404c7884a8/blockmgr-3226ed7e-f8e5-40a2-bfb1-ffabb51cd0e0, already present as root for deletion.
15/12/09 17:12:30 INFO Utils: Shutdown hook called
15/12/09 17:12:30 INFO Utils: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-30d61b03-0b1c-4250-b68e-c2404c7884a8/httpd-7f2572c2-5677-446e-a80a-6f9d05ee2891
15/12/09 17:12:30 INFO Utils: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-30d61b03-0b1c-4250-b68e-c2404c7884a8
```

Comment: Which version of Spark are you using?

Comment: I am using Spark version 1.4.1

Comment: Can you switch ON the debug logs for Tomcat and Spark send across complete Trace. Spark have its own Shutdown hooks which anyways gets executed to stop the Spark Context and clean up the resources.

Comment: I have added Spark log to the question. From the Tomcat side I can only see  [exec] Result: 50

Comment: try changing spark.local.dir to some other directory (by default it is "/tmp") in "$SPARK_HOME/conf/Spark-default.conf". My suspect is that while Spark Shutdown hook is invoked it deletes the temporary/ scratch directory for its executors and to me it seems like tomcat and Spark share the same temporary directory which is "/tmp". Adding Tomcat logs in debug mode will also help in identifying sequence of actions performed before shutting it down.

Comment: I tried by setting spark.local.dir to a different folder. But no luck. I enabled Tomcat debug logs but didn't find any further logs. I am running both Spark context and Tomcat in a single JVM. I wonder whether that model doesn't support.

Answer (score 0):

Use **spark://hostname:7077** as spark master while setting master in **SparkConf** if you are using IP address in place of host name.

I have faced the same issue, it got resolved by using host name in spark master instead of using IP address.

Regards,
Hokam

Comment: I am using host name for Spark conf. No luck.